# PHP find version number and add string as variable

Tags: php

I have a file CHANGELOG.md, that looks likes:

```
# Changelog


## 3.2.0 - 2014-05-22

- iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet 
- doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui

## 3.1.2 - 2014-03-22

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, 
- quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et


## 3.1.1 - 2014-03-25

- facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. 
- Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
```

I want to use php to find the most recent changelog version and add it to a variable `$changelog`

I was thinking I could use the fopen() and fseek() functions in php, but I've never quite done that before.  What do you think the best way to achieve pulling this string out?

Comment: You're more likely to get good responses here if you try something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using regular expressions:

```
$subject=file_get_contents($changeLogFile);
if(preg_match("/## ([0-9]*?[.][0-9]*?[.][0-9]*?) - ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/", $subject, $matches))
{
    $changelog=$matches[1];
    $changelogdate=$matches[2];
}
echo "$changelog $changelogdate";
```

This does what you are looking for and even datelog. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting that file string to array using `explode()`

`$cLogArray = explode('##', file_get_contents($changeLogFile))`

and than take needed part:

`$changeLog = $cLogArray[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pattern remains constant, you can explode the string a couple of times and extract the version number. May not be ideal, but it is a quick fix.

```
$str = file_get_contents('path/to/CHANGELOG.md');
$first_explode = explode('##', $str);
$second_explode = explode("\n", $first_explode[1]);
$changelog = $second_explode[0];
echo $changelog;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HqDd1x)

Answer (score 0):

This one extracts you only the version number like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  3.2.0
    [1] =>  3.1.2
    [2] =>  3.1.1
)
```

I used this RegEx: `/## [0-9.]* - /`  which will find, e.g. `## 3.2.0 -`.
Then, I iterated and removed the `##` and `-`.

Here is the code I used:

```
$a = file_get_contents($changeLogFile)
$cLogArray = preg_match_all('/## [0-9.]* - /', $a, $n);

foreach ($b as $v) {
    $result = str_replace(' - ', '', str_replace('## ', '', $v));
}
```

You don't need to sort your array if the highest number is always on top, but if you wanted, add this step at last:

`rsort($result);`

After doing this, `$result[0]` will always be the highest number.